# php, how to simplify a php script?

Tags: php, short

im not sure this is a good question to post but here is my issue. I have an `if` statement that is getting way too long and i was wondering if there is some other kind of syntax to shorten it out:

```
if (($time1 <= $one_day)&&
    ($time2 <= $one_day)&&
    ($time3 <= $one_day)&&
    ($time4 <= $one_day)&&
    ($time5 <= $one_day)&&
    ($time1 != NULL)&&
    ($time2 != NULL)&&
    ($time3 != NULL)&&
    ($time4 != NULL)&&
    ($time5 != NULL)){
    //do sometihng
}
```

this is one example but i have a similar one that goes up to `..&&($time15 <= $one_day)`.

the statement is pretty self explanatory, `$time1, $time2, etc` can come back empty so i have to check if they are `NULL` or not

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: What if any of those times are 0?

Comment: bases on my script, it can't. but good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the common stuff in a function:

```
function validate_time($time, $one_day) {
    return $time <= $one_day && $time != NULL;
}
if (validate_time($time1, $one_day) &&
    validate_time($time2, $one_day) &&
    validate_time($time3, $one_day) &&
    validate_time($time4, $one_day) &&
    validate_time($time5, $one_day)) {
    // do something
}
```

You may want to refactor code and eliminate the need for copying & pasting those checks. Another way to get the job done:

```
while (true) {
    foreach (array($time1, $time2, $time3, $time4, $time5) as $time) {
        if ($time > $one_day || $time == NULL) {
            break 2;
        }
    }
    // do something
    break;
}
```

The above could be put in a function as well which would make the while-loop and `break` keyword redundant. Replace `break 2` by return then.

Comment: Might be better to use `!= NULL` rather than `is_null()`, apparently it's [more than 14 times quicker](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/03/29/php-is_null-vs-null/) :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using an array for you variables would help. The you can iterate over them and check.

Answer (score 1):

Put the times in an array and have a `for` loop to do the checking.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using 15 similar but different variables, consider using an array.

Answer (score 1):

If you must (or want to) keep the original variable names and not use an array here is the good solution (for $time1 to $time5):

```
$ok = true;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
{
    $var =& ${'time'.$i};
    if ( ! ($var <= $one_day && $var != NULL))
    {
        $ok = false;
    }
}

if ($ok)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Could simplify futher with `if ($var > $one_day) { $ok = false;break; }

Answer (score 0):

You can set all the values into an Array and compare it using an For Loop.

Answer (score 0):

A functionised version which should help with your reuse. This is similar to Lekensteyns code.

```
$times = array(
    'time',
    'time',
    'time',
    'time',
    'time',
);

function validateTime($checks, $limit) 
{
    foreach($checks as $check) {
        if($check == null || $check > $limit) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

if(validateTime($times,$one_day) == true) {
  //codey code.
}
```